# Sharepoint Online "404 File Not Found" Error From 365 Office Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I think accidentally deleted the default team site from SharePoint online.  Now I get a "404 File Not Found" message when I click the SharePoint link from the Office 365 home page.

The broken url is https://*domain*.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx

I don't see the deleted page in the SharePoint admin site-> Sites-> Deleted Sites, so I cannot restore it from there.

I am very new at SharePoint, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the user had deleted the home.aspx page. So i navigated to the sites' site pages 
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/SitePages, i.e. accessing the site, and from there navigated to the recycle bin where i restored the home.aspx page

Answer (score 0):

The root site shouldn't be able to be removed. A warning alert appears when trying to remove it but don't let go further. Maybe, this setting has change recently and the site can be removed but having this kind of issues.

I think you should contact Microsoft support in order to help you restoring the root site collection and making all the default pages available for all users.

Comment: That was good advice jaloplo.  I talked to support, you can only see the deleted collection in the classic admin view (not the modern).  I was able to restore it from the classic view and everything is now working.

Comment: Thank you. Remember to vote up or down responses and/or comments.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by assigning a different page as the Homepage and reassigning the Home.aspx as the homepage. You probably did not delete the site by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered situation when without valuable reason I've lost access to my SharePoint communication site's root `/` page, but was able to access it by `/SitePages/Home.aspx` page. Documents in search also became inaccessible because of documents' subfolders renaming. It's because of they have not been reindexed.

Also, in my case, [resetting welcome page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45688/redirect-sharepoint-root-to-another-homepage-site) is required as I think.

Answer (score 0):

Go to site contents > site pages >
Right-click the page that is your homepage > select Make as Home Page...
that should do the trick